# Cannot open any PDF file using Okular

Tags: 11.04, pdf, okular

Today I found online saying that Okular is a very good document viewer. So I installed it from the software center.
After the installation, Okular could not open any PDF files. Actually it could not open file. It always complained that "Cannot find a plug in..." and "Could not open ... pdf file".

I looked up on this site, and found somebody said we should delete the related configuration files under `~/.kde/share/`. But I didn't found those files there.

BTW, I'm using the Unity desktop.

Comment: to get more info open the document from the terminal with okular like this `okular mypdf.pdf` and add the output to you question alternatively you can add `nohup` to the begining of the command and any messages will be added to nohup.out making it easy to copy them, the command would look like this `nohup okular /home/user/mypdf.pdf`

Comment: @Jorge Castro: Thank you very much for your reply. From the output, it seems that I don't have the permission to create folder in /home/username/.kde/. So I added sudo to run the command, and it worked. How can I open the pdf file directly with clicking the pdf? Thank you.  The output is as follows:

Comment: (Continued) trying to create local folder /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun: Permission denied
okular(8956)/kdeui (KIconLoader) KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase 
trying to create local folder /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun: Permission denied
trying to create local folder /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun: Permission denied
trying to create local folder /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun: Permission denied

Comment: I change the mode using chmod of the directory /home/cheng/.kde/chache and /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun to 777, and it works now. I don't know if there are other better ways to do this.

Comment: @user26215 Welcome to askubuntu. The way this site works is to edit your original question and add the information there, that way we have it up front instead of buried in the comments. Just click edit and paste what you've been putting in the comments there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem so I tried the command:

```
$kbuildsycoca4
```

but it felt to run, because I needed to install some kde libs. Then I installed such libs typing:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin
```

After that Okular was able to open PDF's.

Is this a bug? I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 in a fresh installation.

Answer (score 2):

The OP posted the solution in a comment

> I change the mode using chmod of the directory /home/cheng/.kde/chache and /home/cheng/.kde/cache-guangchun to 777, and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this misleading error as well. In my case the console log indicated:

```
okular(30121)/kdecore (trader): KMimeTypeTrader: couldn't find service type "okular/Generator" 
Please ensure that the .desktop file for it is installed; then run kbuildsycoca4. 
okular(30121)/okular (app) Okular::Document::openDocument: No plugin for mimetype '"application/pdf"'.
```

As instructed I ran kbuildsycoca4:

```
~% kbuildsycoca4
kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(30132) kdemain: Reusing existing ksycoca
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::recreate: Recreating ksycoca file ("/var/tmp/kdecache-tmetro/ksycoca4", version 205)
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::createEntry: new: "okularGenerator.desktop" in servicetypes
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::createEntry: new: "libokularGenerator_xps.desktop" in services
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::createEntry: new: "okularEPub.desktop" in services
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::createEntry: new: "okularPlucker.desktop" in services
kbuildsycoca4(30132) KBuildSycoca::createEntry: new: "libokularGenerator_fax.desktop" in services
[...etc for several screen...]
```

After that okular was able to load PDFs.

Seems like a packaging bug. That should have ran from a post-install script.